# Issues with radiant in centos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, radiant

I have issues with radiant cms version 0.8.2.In Application,when i click on submit on form application got an error uninitialized controller which is in radiant/app/controller.

error :

NameError (uninitialized constant ResourceController):
  vendor/extensions/smart/app/controllers/quote_requests_controller.rb:1
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in`run'

/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`start'

/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in`start'

/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`start'

/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in`start'

ResourceController is in radiant/app/controllers/admin/resource_controller.rb

and in the first line of quote_requests_controller.rb, "class QuoteRequestsController <  ResourceController::Base" is there.

rails 2.3.14
ruby 1.8.7
rubygems-update (1.4.2)
radiant 0.8.2

i was done googling for this issue please help me to figure out error.

Thanking You,
Nirav

Answer (score 0):

You say ResourceController is in radiant/app/controllers/admin/resource_controller.rb
A class placed there should actually be Admin::ResourceController, not just ResourceController.

The class definition line would then read: "class QuoteRequestsController < Admin::ResourceController". However! That class already exists; it's what most admin controllers inherit from.

Either come up with a new name for your controller, or move it out of the admin/ folder.

Comment: "class Admin::ResourceController < ApplicationController"
   this is in resource_controller.rb file. and i also tried to put resource_controller.rb file out of admin. but it gives error      LoadError (Expected /home/ec2-user/rubygems-1.4.2/new/vendor/radiant/app/controllers/resource_controller.rb to define ResourceController):
  vendor/extensions/smartmove/app/controllers/quote_requests_controller.rb:1

Comment: Thanks Benny ,                                                      i also tried to replace "class QuoteRequestsController < ResourceController::Base" to "class QuoteRequestsController < Admin::ResourceController" but still it gets an error will be same and  i search by googling to add require "resource_controller" in top of the controller but it doesn't help to solve an error.   Thanking You,                                                   Nirav

Comment: Hey, sorry I lost track of this.
Forget everything I said before (Leave Admin::ResourceController alone!)..
QuoteRequestsController should probably inherit from SiteController or even ActionController::Base. Was this working before or are you developing this?